# Liferay 7 ADT - get organization logo

Tags: html, templates, liferay, adt, freemarker

I'm trying to get the logo from the organization (who created the asset) out of my freemarker ADT.
Do you guys have any ideas how to do that?

My Idea:
Get OrganizationID from UserID
Get Logo from OrganizationID.

I tried that to get the OrganizationID:

```
<#assign userUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.persistence.UserUtil"]>
```

But it gives my a classNotFoundException...

thanks in advance!

Comment: the class the it's not found is  `com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.persistence.UserUtil `?

Answer (score 2):

So i solved the problem like this:

```
<#assign UserLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalService")>
<#assign logoId = UserLocalService.getUser(curEntry.getUserId()).getOrganizations()[0].getLogoId()>
<#assign logoPath = "/image/layout_set_logo?img_id=" + logoId>
```